# Loading GIF in a GridView using Glide stops currently playing GIF when loading other

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm experimenting with Glide to load and play .GIF in a GridView. There are a couple of issues I have experienced.

1. The GIF doesn't play after the thumbnail is displayed. It waits for a certain amount of time (maybe after a certain number of GIF is already loaded) before it starts playing
2. When scrolling through the GridView, all the other GIF stops playing when loading the new set of GIF.

I'm not really sure, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the frame processing in the background. Knowing this, is there any way I can fix or at least improve the user experience from the mentioned issues?